# XCode 11.4 UISearchBar not visible

Tags: xcode

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/4363809-uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started

Here is the relevant code.
The only problem is the search bar is not visible. In the tutorial he creates a UISearchController and the search bar miraculously appears (though its not in the storyboard anywhere, so I can't explain how it works for him):

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class PlacesViewController: UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var places11:Results<Place11>?
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    
    var filteredPlaces: [Place11] = []
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        places11 = PlaceService.getPlaces11()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Permits"
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        definesPresentationContext = true
}

    func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String) {
        let array = places11?.toArray(type: Place11.self)
        filteredPlaces = array!.filter { (place: Place11) -> Bool in
            let bool2 = (place.description.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) )
            return bool2
        }
        
        tableView.reloadData()
    } 

    
    var isSearchBarEmpty: Bool {
        return searchController.searchBar.text?.isEmpty ?? true
    }
    
    var isFiltering: Bool {
        return searchController.isActive && !isSearchBarEmpty
    }
    

}



extension PlacesViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
        let text = searchBar.text!
        filterContentForSearchText(text)
        
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes the search bar appear, in the navigation bar, is this line: `navigationItem.searchController = searchController`. Are you in a navigation interface? If not, the search bar has no place to go.

Comment: Matt, you can see I have that line in viewDidLoad(). Can you explain "in a navigation interface?" Thanks

Comment: Of course I can see it. I'm telling you that unless your view controller is the direct child of a UINavigationController, that line does nothing.

Comment: OK I just found out about navigation controllers from https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementNavigation.html . I understand you con't have a navigation bar unless your embedded in a navigation controller. Tanks

Comment: Okay, I'll give that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

What makes the search bar appear, in the navigation bar, is this line:

```
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

The problem is that your view controller is not part of a navigation interface. There is no navigation controller and no navigation bar, so the search bar has no place to go.